# How to extract a payload from a noisy modulated wave signal

Tags: c++, signals, noise, fftw, wave

I have an array of double values which represent modulated radio signal with encoded data. It can be display like this(bottom graph):

[image]

In the lower graph you can see the noisy signal from which I need to get the default bit sequence. For phase modulation I have this algorithm: make an FFT (or DFT) for the given array, calculate φ for each complex number read from the FFT result, where φ = atan(Q/I), Q is the real part of the complex number and I is the imaginary part of the complex number, then calculate the sum of the numbers φ for each bit and if the sum is greater than L, mark the bit as 1 (otherwise 0).

I wrote some code, but it doesn't look like it works correctly

```cpp
std::vector<double> y_axis = generateWave(); // The noised signal

fftw_complex * out = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(fftw_malloc(sizeof (fftw_complex) * y_axis.size()));
fftw_complex * in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(fftw_malloc(sizeof (fftw_complex) * y_axis.size()));

for (std::size_t i{0}; i < y_axis.size(); i++) {
    in[i][0] = y_axis[i]; in[i][1] = 0.0;
}

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(y_axis.size(), in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan); fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

std::vector<double> result_vector(y_axis.size());
for (std::size_t i{0}; i < result_vector.size(); i++) {
    result_vector[i] = std::atan(out[i][0] / out[i][1]);
}

const std::size_t per_bit = result_vector.size() / bit_sequence.size();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bit_sequence.size(); i++) {
    double current_sum = 0.0;
    for (std::size_t j{0}; j < per_bit; j++) current_sum += result_vector[i * per_bit + j];
    std::cerr << bit_sequence[i] << " " << current_sum << std::endl;
}

fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);
```

Now I just print φ numbers sum for every bit to get the L value, but sometimes L for 0 is greater than for 1 and it is impossible to extract the correct bit sequence...

P.S. Noise power is measured in decibels
P.S. This algorithm was given by my teacher and should work, but I could have understood or written it wrong. Thank

Comment: Looks like you'll need to middle out the lower peaks from your graph.

Comment: i think your demodulation method is incorrect, as most of the fft result is white noise, and its phase is also going to be noise, and you are just summing up noise, if the fft is set up correctly then only 1 bin of the fft will contain the signal with some noise, and the rest of the bins will only contain noise, so summing up noise isn't a good demodulation strategy, and i doubt that's the method your teacher has mentioned, and on a side note i think a matched filter is going to do a better job at this than fft, as your signal is only a single tone, and you also need to chop it up into bits.